# How to make event listeners works when <select> is trigerred?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I wanna handle keydown event when I am choosing an option.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('keydown');
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>keydown should works anywhere.</p>
  <p>Open the select below and try to keypress, event listener is like deactivated.</p>
  <select>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it works ?

Comment: This sounds more like an XY problem. What do you want to do with the select when a user hits a key on their keyboard on the document itself?

Comment: if you tell us which is the final result you want to obtain we can find maybe a different approach

Comment: The final result is: console.log anything on keydown when select is opened and without custom select

Answer (score 1):

The keydown event, when the select is open, is used to select options starting with that letter.

If you want to append keydown events, you will have to make a custom element that resembles a select element with options.

Link to implementation:

https://andrejgajdos.com/custom-select-dropdown/

Comment: Thanks but I cannot because I need browsers selects and it's not same select on chrome / ie / firefox / etc

Answer (score 0):

your keydown event is working as intended.  Click on the document and then press any ASCII key - say any letter and you will see the conse.log().  To get what you might be looking for change keydown to a click event

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('keydown');
});

function myFunction(){
console.log('select')
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>keydown should works anywhere.</p>
  <p>Open the select below and try to keypress, event listener is like deactivated.</p>
  <select onclick='myFunction()'>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: May you read the second <p> in the snippet ? > Open the select below and try to keypress, event listener is like deactivated.